# if statement code style with returns

Tags: c++, if-statement, coding-style, styles, return

Say I have this functions:

```
inline bool fileExists(const char *name) {
  FILE *file;
  if (fopen_s(&file, name, "r") == 0)
  {
    fclose(file);
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Is better doing the above one, or this one?

```
inline bool fileExists(const char *name) {
  FILE *file;
  if (fopen_s(&file, name, "r") == 0)
  {
    fclose(file);
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Are there difference at compile time?

Comment: No, generated code will be exactly the same with any **decent compiler** (in a release build). A terrible compiler may emit one extra jump for the else branch.

Comment: There might be a small difference, but you won't notice it, talking about nanoseconds here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is mostly a matter of opinion. IMO the second form is better, because it will always provide a return value. If you modify the function to do something different in the else clause you can forget to add the return value. In the above sample the generated code is the same.

Answer (score 4):

Efficiency isn't an issue, no. A half-decent compiler would know what to do. And for this simple function, logically it should be the same. For larger functions though, with lots more logic, the second one is slightly better because it guarantees that the function always returns.

Either that, or prefer a **single point of return** (this doesn't necessarily apply here though as the function is relatively small). This can help the compiler generate better, more efficient code, in some cases (multiple return statements hinder RVO):

```
inline bool fileExists(const char *name) {
  FILE *file;
  bool exists = false;
  if (fopen_s(&file, name, "r") == 0)
  {
    fclose(file);
    exists = true;
  }
  return exists;
}
```

Comment: Even though "single point of return" has been advocated for many years, I think (and AFAICT I'm not the only one) that it often decreases readability by increasing levels of indentation and keeping variables in scope for too long. I tend to prefer "early return" (as done in the second snippet of the OP), i.e. get rid of unusual paths at the start of a function, then proceed with the main behavior. The argument about RVO still stands, though.

Comment: @LucTouraille it's of course a case-by-case situation. I'm not a fan of "always" rules.

Answer (score 1):

No, the semantic analyis of the compiler, and also the optimizer afterwards, will result to the same object code.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, absolutely certainly not an issue. `fopen` will take microseconds (unless the directory with the actual file isn't cached, in which case it is several milliseconds), and you are worrying about one extra jump or not - which is maybe 4-6 clockcycles.

In general, I prefer the "one return statement", but it can get quite messy at times, in which case I prefer the second of your options. Nearly always, the code will become something like this, as "compilers" also prefer a single exit point:

```
bool fileExists(const char *name) {
  FILE *file;
  bool ret_val;
  if (fopen_s(&file, name, "r") == 0)
  {
    fclose(file);
    ret_val = true;
    goto end;
  }
  ret_val = false
end:
  return ret_val;
}
```

Sometimes, if the code is very complex - especially if the code is "simple to begin with" and then gets complex, the compiler will have multiple return points from a function, but the above scenario is fairly typical. [I'm NOT suggesting you use `goto` in your code tho'. The compiler is perfectly capable of making the difference]

Oh, and I suspect using `inline` isn't really going to make much difference on performance in this case.

Comment: The inline could be there to prevent multiple definitions though.

Comment: Sure, but I also don't see much point in putting it in a header - compared to the overhead of actually opening the file, there's very little saving in making it inline - and presumably if it collides with another name in the system we should use a different name.

Comment: Ops, I forgot the static inline ... My function only exists inside one .cpp file.

Comment: If it's static, then the compiler will decide to inline it or not, no matter what you do [barring "-fno-inline" or similar compiler options]